# converting treemap to highcharter comes up with blank

Tags: r, treemap, r-highcharter

The treemap is ploting fine but when I enter it into highcharter the viewer shows up blank.

```
tm <- treemap(M, index = c("Order", "Family"),
              vSize = "n", vColor = "n",
              type = "value", palette = viridis(6))

hctreemap(tm)
```

Comment: you can use the development version of highcharter, and try the new `hctreemap2` function, you can see some examples in http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/hctreemap2

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.